# DataGrid column of buttons: images are not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, image, imagebutton

I have this Xaml that generates a column of buttons in a DataGrid. The problem is that the images don't show! How I can resolve this problem?

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Output" Binding="{Binding Output}" Width="*"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Input" Binding="{Binding Input}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Click="Add_Button_Click" Visibility="Visible" Height="16" Width="16">
                    <Image Height="16" Source="/Resources/plus.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="16"/>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: does button itself shows? Do you have anything in the place of image, or it works as there were no <image ...>  in your code?

Comment: The buttons show themselves! The images not!

Comment: Did you actually add an image called "plus.png" to the Resources folder at the root folder of your project? What is the build action of the file?

Comment: have you tried to remove height and width from image? If you have Stretch="fill" it might be useless. Or remove visibility from button? If @Mukesh Methaniya's answer didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

add button content and put image inside Button.Content

```
<Button >
  <Button.Content>
     <Image x:Name="KeyName"  Source="pack://Resources/image.png"  />
  </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: Source="pack://Resources/image.png" ?